# Symmetric expressions in excel matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

I sometimes work with symmetric matrices in MS-Excel (both v2007 and v2003).

Is there an option to help me to copy expressions from the lower triangle to the upper one?

It should be something like copy and paste/transponse but those functions normally work only with rectangular areas.

in the added picture you can see an exemple of an expression that I have to replicate by linking the symmetric value in the superior triangle of the matrix.
[image: symmetric expression matrix]

Comment: I have faces the same issue, and I either manually setup formulas to pull values, or use a combination of `INDEX()`, `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions. I supposed there is a VBA solution out there.

Comment: This is a problem that might require a programming answer. I vote to keep question the open.

Comment: @ja72, I agree - and even if it doesn't require VBA *(shameless plug for my answer)*, programming can be excel formulas - there are (currently) 1688 questions about excel formulas.

Comment: @ale ... still no answer that fits your needs? Please comment or accept one of the answers - thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the number in the appropriate cell, we can use `OFFSET` and the cell address the forms the base of the table. Note that the formula will produce a *Circular Reference` error if entered in on the diagonal. The formula will work for both sides of the diagonal - you just have to decide which one will hold the data, and which will hold the formula.

Offset takes Row and Column to decide the target. By subtracting the base cell row and column from the current position, we can invert the row and columns, and get the data.

Using your example, with the origin of the table in **B2**, we end up with the following formula:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2),ROW()-ROW($B$2))
```

you can copy this formula into the cells, and get the reflection. Now you have the number, you can do any calculation you require on the reflection. Using your example, this would make the formula:

```
=10-OFFSET($B$2,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2),ROW()-ROW($B$2))
```

Result:

[image: example]

Using `INDEX` to make it non volatile would change the formula slightly. First, we would need a reference to the entire table, not just the top cell. Second, we would need to add 1 to the row/column calculation, as it refers to the first cell as row/column `1`, not an offset of `0` as the previous formula.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$K$11,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2)+1,ROW()-ROW($B$2)+1)
```

and your example of 10-Cell would become:

```
=10-INDEX($B$2:$K$11,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2)+1,ROW()-ROW($B$2)+1)
```

Comment: +1. This approach is very versatile. One can even add a named range as `MyTranspose = Evaluate(10-OFFSET($B$2,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2),ROW()-ROW($B$2)))` and then use it at `=MyTranspose` in all of these cells. Let alone that it can refer to a cell instead of 10 and therefore change the symmetric element dynamically!

Comment: +1 - I would use a similar approach - but always prefer `INDEX` to `OFFSET`. It offers the same functionality, but in non-volatile. Which is a huge advantage in larger calculations!

Comment: @PeterAlbert, good idea - I've added the appropriate formula into the answer

Answer (score 3):

As one of the above answers demonstrates, this can be done by using Excel formulas. I however find this to be a very tedious procedure. Especially if this is something you need to do on a regular basis. In that case VBA could save you a lot of time.

The following code will work on a square selection and fill the rest of the matrix no matter if it is the lower- or upper part of the matrix that is pre-filled.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillSymetricMatrix()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim SelRng As Range
    Dim FillArea As String
    Dim FRow As Integer
    Dim FCol As Integer

    Set SelRng = Selection
    FRow = SelRng.Rows(1).Row
    FCol = SelRng.Columns(1).Column

    'Returns information about which area to fill
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(FRow + SelRng.Rows.Count - 1, FCol).Value <> vbNullString Then       'Lower filled
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(FRow, FCol + SelRng.Columns.Count - 1).Value = vbNullString Then 'Upper empty
            FillArea = "Upper"
        Else
            FillArea = "Error"
        End If
    Else
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(FRow, FCol + SelRng.Columns.Count - 1).Value <> vbNullString Then 'Upper filled
            FillArea = "Lower"
        Else
            FillArea = "Error"
        End If

    End If

    'Determines if the selection is square
    If SelRng.Rows.Count <> SelRng.Columns.Count Then FillArea = "Error"


    'Fills empty area of the square (symetric) matrix
    Select Case FillArea
        Case Is = "Upper"
            For i = 0 To SelRng.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
                For j = 0 To SelRng.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
                    If i <= j Then ActiveSheet.Cells(i + FRow, j + FCol).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(j + FRow, i + FCol).Value
                Next j
            Next i

        Case Is = "Lower"
            For i = 0 To SelRng.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
                For j = 0 To SelRng.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
                    If i <= j Then ActiveSheet.Cells(j + FRow, i + FCol).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + FRow, j + FCol).Value
                Next j
            Next i

        Case Else
            MsgBox "The procedure cannot be performed on the current selection!"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with VBA. Start with an un-filled table and a button.

[image: SCREEN1]

Then make the button run the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub symmButton_Click()
    MakeSymmetric Range("B2")
End Sub

Public Sub MakeSymmetric(ByRef r As Range)

    Dim M As Long
    M = CountCols(r)

    Dim vals() As Variant
    vals = r.Resize(M, M).Value2

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 2 To M
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            vals(i, j) = vals(j, i)
        Next j
    Next i

    r.Resize(M, M).Value2 = vals
End Sub


Public Function CountCols(ByRef r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountCols = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(0, 1)) Then
        CountCols = 1
    Else
        CountCols = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    End If
End Function
```

and finally observe the results

[image]

Comment: This seems go in the right way. But I have a question: if instead of a symmetric matrix I have to put a symmetric expression? (eg: trisup matrix integer value between [0;10], triinf matrix integer value with this expression: [10-symmetric value]? With your way is possible to set an expression instead of the symmetric value?

Comment: @Ale what is next, a sparse solver for Excel? J/k, it is possible to do that. Can you edit the OP with an example so the problem is better defined.

Comment: added picture (note that I am not so able with VBA)

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you need is a function which returns the "diagonal" value of a square matrix, e.g. for any `X(j,k)` return `X(k,j)`

Try this:

```
Function DIAGONAL(Arg As Range, Reference As Range) As Variant
Dim MyRow As Long, MyCol As Long

    If Reference.Rows.Count <> Reference.Columns.Count Then
        DIAGONAL = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Else
        MyRow = Arg.Row - Reference.Row + 1
        MyCol = Arg.Column - Reference.Column + 1
        If MyRow < 1 Or MyCol < 1 Or MyRow > Reference.Rows.Count Or MyCol > Reference.Columns.Count Then
            DIAGONAL = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Else
            DIAGONAL = Reference(MyCol, MyRow)
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

once you entered this function in VBA, you can use it inside or outside your square matrix ... you just need to ensure that your argument (parameter: Arg) is within the matrix (parameter: Reference) ... or you get an #N/A error. Or you get a #REF error if the matrix isn't square.

So in your example you would enter into B4: `=10-DIAGONAL(B4,$B$2:$K$11)` and copy this throughout the lower triangle.

You can even transpose a complete matrix ... in your screen shot, move to cell B13, enter `=DIAGONAL(B2,$B$2:$K$11)` and copy 9x down & right

No buttons, no need to explicitely start a Sub ... any size of n x n matrix, handles strings and numbers, ...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Sean's solution, I would also use formulas. In order to get the transposed value, use this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$G$7,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2)+1,ROW()-ROW($B$2)+1)
```

If you want to do a more complex operation (e.g. `=10-[transposedValue]`), I'd recommend you use a named range: Insert a new name, e.g. `TransposedValue`in the Name Manager. Instead of a cell link, provide the above formula. Now you can literally write the following formula in your matrix:

```
=10-TransposedValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(D2), ROW(D2)))`

Explnation: you may remember we use coordinates with numbers to represent a location in Cartesian Coordinates System. So, it's easy to get a diagonal symmetric value e.g. just change (2, 3) to (3, 2).

But in Excel, we need a wordaround if we want to do so. Because, address is marked by a combination of a letter and a digit, say `B2`. You can't just change `B2` to `2B`.
Luckily, we can still use numbers to represent a cell by leveraging the power of COW() and COLUMN().

In the image below, `C2` and `B3` are symmetrical. This shows how to put the value of `C2` to `B3`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have this way. As you said copy paste transpose work on rectangular range. And your problem is that you have a triangular range.

You will love this....

**1).** Select the square range containing your upper triangular matrix and Copy.

**2).** Select a **cell** in an empty place and do the following two steps

- a.) Paste Special - Values
- b.) Paste Special - Values - Transpose - Skip Blanks

And you have got your symmetric matrix :-)

Anil.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing together Ja72's fill code with SeanC c's Excel function code, I think I can make a generic matrix template that is properly prefilled with the dynamic Excel formula.  So dynamic, and can be reused without any copy and paste.

```
Public Sub MakeSymmetric(ByRef r As Range)

    Dim M As Long
    M = 300
    ' Was CountCols(r), but I just limited to 300 columns for now

    Dim vals() As Variant
    vals = r.Resize(M, M).Value2

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 2 To M
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            vals(j, i) = "=OFFSET($B$2,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$2),ROW()-ROW($B$2))"

        Next j
            'Make diagonal down the middle show ---
            vals(j, i) = "---"
    Next i
    vals(1, 1) = "---"

    r.Resize(M, M).Value2 = vals
End Sub

Sub FillSymmetric()
    MakeSymmetric Range("B2")
End Sub
```

I don't really know any VB though, so I haven't quite figured out how to fill the header yet.  I don't know Stackoverflow yet either, but I will try to add a picture.
[Original List to Matrixize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3NZu.jpg)

[Dynamically transposing values typed in SouthWest half to NorthEast half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnNBx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Making the formula from C.W. more generic (similar to Peter Albert), this will help when your matrix is not starting at `A1` but e.g. in `C10`:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(C11)-COLUMN($C$10)+1,ROW(C11)-ROW($C$10)+1))`

So, subtract the origin row/column and add 1.